# Galaxy Nexus 6:30 minutes to copy 128MB over WiFi, is it normal?

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-nexus, lan

I use the Galaxy Nexus GT-I9250 and the WiFi is very slow, I copied a video (128MB) from my computer and it completed in 6:30 minutes, is that normal? It seems slower than over 3G.
I used ES File Explorer to copy and I was logged in with the Windows User/pass.

Comment: Is it consistently slow? How about its speed on other WiFi networks?

Comment: Depending on your WiFi signal strength, it might be slower or faster. Given an average speed of 30 MBit/s (at a 54 MBit connection, that sounds quite reasonable; also taking into account that CIFS has a little overhead), the transfer should have taken between ~30s and a minute. Everything above that I wouldn't count reasonable. Check your WiFi speed, as Peanut already pointed out. Other WiFi networks on the same channel might also reduce speed; in that case, configure your WiFi AP to use a different channel.

Comment: Is your copmuter on wifi, or a wired network? Copying between two wifi devices on the same AP is normally far slower than copying from a wifi to a wired device, due to collision problems.

Comment: I was copying from a laptop on same WiFi router. I will try copying a similar file when computer is on cable and test the WiFi channel too, then reply. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you were both uploading and downloading simultaneously and upload speeds are usually much slower (I figured yours must have been around .33 MB/s), then that doesn't seem totally unreasonable depending on other variables.